# How to set multiple data effect in html

Tags: jquery, html, animation

Hello I need help for multiple data effect in html

I've tried below code but it only apply first effect. I have to add both effect to this div . Is there any work around or proper approach to do that ?

```
<div  data-effect="fadeInRightOpacity fadeInLeftBig" ></div>
```

Comment: Try provide us with a bit more information, are you using a plugin? is it for jQuery, then show us.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Thank's for comment i am using Owl Jquery slider.

Comment: Can you provide us with an example where you use `data-effect` since i can not see it being used in the demo on Owl jquery